# With Craft Commerce, how can I call getAllStates from my own plugin via ajax?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to call `$states = craft()->commerce_states->getAllStates();` from within my own plugin, via an ajax request.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest()) {
    return $this->returnJson(['states' => craft()->commerce_states->getAllStates()]);
}
```

The above will return this:

```
Object {states: Array[72]}
```

However, as I'm walking myself through it, I can see that the original call:

```
var states = {{ craft.commerce.statesArray|json_encode|raw }};
```

Gives me these objects:

```
Object {13: Object, 38: Object, 233: Object}
Object {13: Object, 38: Object, 233: Object}
```

So it's pretty obvious i'm not calling the correct method. I am using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) within my project and having the javascript right in the template is returning errors - it can't access jquery.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `getAllStates()` to get the same data back as the twig call:

```
var states = {{ craft.commerce.statesArray|json_encode|raw }};
```

Within your plugin you need to call `getStatesGroupedByCountries()`

**MyPlugin.php**

```
if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest()) {
    return $this->returnJson(['states' => craft()->commerce_states->getStatesGroupedByCountries()]);
}
```